# Задал массивы: kol,kol2,kol3. При использование их компилятор пишет ошибку cannot be resolved a variable

Tags: java

```
package Paskage;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class frt{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner cs = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String[][] kol = { 
      {"Червы","Пики","Буби","Крести"},
      { "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" ,"7" ,"8" , "9" , "10" , "Валет" , "Дама" , "Король" , "Туз"}
    };
    String[][] kol2 = new String[kol.length][kol[kol.length].length];
    String[][] kol3 = new String[kol.length][kol[kol.length].length];
    
    System.out.println("Введите колличесво игроков");
    int r = cs.nextInt();   
}


//Раздача карт 
int ch2 = 0,ch = 0;
while(r!=0) {
    System.out.print(kol2[ch][ch2]+" ");
    ++ch2;
    if(ch2==13) {ch2 = 0; ++ch;}
    System.out.print(kol2[ch][ch2]+" ");
    ++ch2;
    if(ch2==13) {ch2 = 0; ++ch;}
    System.out.print(kol2[ch][ch2]+" ");
    ++ch2;
    if(ch2==13) {ch2 = 0; ++ch;}
    System.out.print(kol2[ch][ch2]+" ");
    ++ch2;
    if(ch2==13) {ch2 = 0; ++ch;}
    System.out.println(kol2[ch][ch2]+" ");
    ++ch2;
    if(ch2==13) {ch2 = 0; ++ch;}
    System.out.println();
    --r;
  }
     
             
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите закрывающую фигурную скобку перед

```
//Раздача карт
```

---

```
new String[kol.length][kol[kol.length - 1].length];
                                     ^^^^
```